# I can't start the weblogic server in Eclipse - The server watcher reported an unknown state

Tags: eclipse, weblogic12c

When I start Eclipse(Mars), I see the weblogic server with both start and stop buttons active. The server modificator is empty - no [starting], [stopped], [running] or something else. And I cannot start nor stop it. At least, half an hour is not enough for it (timeouts are already set to large numbers). 
The situation does not change after:

- restarting Eclipse
- killing Eclipse and java processes in the task manager
- restarting the computer
- deleting the server in Eclipse and connecting to it back.
- -clean at eclipse start
- Erasing and reinstalling the Eclipse

The console output is empty.

Logs in Oracle_home are empty - no changes for the last 3 hours.

Four hours ago server ran and stopped OK. Then began to do it more and more slowly and it came to this.

Of course, I understand, that total delete of weblogic server installations with all domains or c:format could help, but is there some less drastic measure?

In the command line the server can be started by the same start script without any problems. So, the problem is obviously in Eclipse. Can I clean it somehow?

Eclipse log gives very interesting line at the try to start the server:

```
The server watcher reported an unknown state
```

The whole description of the problem is:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.M20150904-0015
java.version=1.8.0_66
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=cs_CZ
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/C:/workspaces/ws_ds8/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic
Error
Mon Jan 04 09:38:33 CET 2016
The server watcher reported an unknown state.
```

An exception stack trace is not available

And I am afraid, this message seems to be absolutely unknown - the line 'The server watcher reported an unknown state' has no hits in Google. What is strange for me, still no messages in WL logs - this message happens before any WL log starts.

Comment: There is no way to understand what might be the cause, and to suggest a solution without more information.

Comment: @Pétur What info? Logs? - they are empty. Really if you will tell me about where to look, it will be enough.

Comment: Fair enough! Upvoted. I can only shoot in the dark! Are you using Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (the server adapter in eclipse is only for basic functionality)? Try launching eclipse in verbose mode (`-verbose` when launched from the command line) and see if that produces some information of use.

Comment: Open the Error Log view in Eclipse and see if anything relevant shows up when you try to start the server.

Comment: @E-Riz It was really a precious piece ov advice. In the log there was a very rare message (look edit)

Comment: @Pétur I have tried -verbose. But it didn't give any additional info on the problem, I have the same line as in the error.log view. ("The server watcher reported an unknown state")

Answer (score 0):

### The server watcher reported an unknown state

message

According to [Configuring and Managing WebLogic Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/overview_lifecycle.html)

```
 UNKNOWN
 If a server instance cannot be contacted, it is in the UNKNOWN state.
```

The only parameters for WL connecting to Eclipse except its folder are:

```
Automated pushing
Use SSL port
Start in debug mode
```

After some attempts I have found, that that problem was caused by checking

### Use SSL port

After the delete of the server connection and reinstalling it without SSL, buttons `stop`, `run` and [stopped/started/starting] state returned to the normal functioning.